# Manga where the main character dies because of an evil god who messes up his reincarnation

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

So in this manga, it turns out the MC died because of an evil god having messed with his fate? So they were going to reincarnate him as an apology but the evil god messed with his life again so his abilities showed up late. He was disowned by his noble family and started working as an adventure, apparently he is strong with magic abilities and cannot be appraised by some others, meets the royal family, teachers the princess I think, and eventually gets adopted by a receptionist ex adventure guy who is the savior of the town.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This sounds a lot like *Shoki Skill Ga Benri Sugite Isekai Seikatsu ga Tanoshisugiru!* which I [identified last week](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245888/looking-for-manga-about-reincarnated-boy-abandoned-by-parents-for-lack-of-skill).

Comment: Yes it was ,thank you very much, I tried looking around before posting my question but didn't see it, I guess the way I searched was wrong.